# Qt - format '%f' expects argument of type 'float*', but argument 2 has type 'double' ^

Tags: c++, qt

I got this at school and it's driving me crazy:

```
float Alas,Tinggi,Luas;
printf("Masukan Nilai Alas Segitiga:");
scanf("%f",Alas);
printf("\nMasukan Nilai Tinggi Segitiga");
scanf("%f",Tinggi);
Luas=0.5*Alas*Tinggi;
printf("\nNilai Luas Segitiga adalah : %f",Luas);
```

So that just returned

```
D:\BUKU\ngitung2\main.cpp:9: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float*', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%f",Alas);
                ^
```

and

```
D:\BUKU\ngitung2\main.cpp:11: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float*', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%f",Tinggi);
                  ^
```

Is there anything wrong? The book says it like this; I read a lot of references in stackoverflow but nothing helped. I already tried `%lf` too but it didn't work.

Comment: Try using the `&` unary "address of" operator...

Comment: Should be `scanf("%lf", &Alas);`. And check the return value of `scanf` to see whether it succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` expects a *pointer* to your variable, not the variable itself. You can easily fix it by passing the address of your variable using the unary `&` (address of) operator:

```
float Alas,Tinggi,Luas;
printf("Masukan Nilai Alas Segitiga:");
scanf("%f",&Alas);
printf("\nMasukan Nilai Tinggi Segitiga");
scanf("%f",&Tinggi);
Luas=0.5*Alas*Tinggi;
printf("\nNilai Luas Segitiga adalah : %f",Luas);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @owacoder mentioned in the comments, `scanf` needs the address of `float` to work.

So it should be:

```
scanf("%f", &Tinggi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the address of (or pointer to) the variable you want to modify to the `scanf` function call.

In your case, the compiler complained that it expected `float*`, i.e. a pointer to a `float` variable.

To pass the pointer to them to the `scanf` function calls, replace the lines with the following:

```
scanf("%f",&Alas);
```

and

```
scanf("%f",&Tinggi);
```